# Element draged but not droped in destnation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

```
        //drag.  
            WebElement From=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='settings']//div[2]"));
             Thread.sleep(3000);
         // drop.
          WebElement To=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel-body']"));     

         Thread.sleep(3000);
         Actions act=new Actions(driver);   
         act.dragAndDrop(From,To).build().perform();    
    }   
  }
```

Comment: Please help me.i'm not getting

Comment: Becarefull with posting passwords, also cross-posting is not allowed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

 Actions act=new Actions(driver.get());  
 act.dragAndDrop(a,b).release().build().perform();
```